# Runtime error when importing gtk.glade Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, runtime-error, glade

While importing gtk.glade in Ubuntu 17.01 it throws a RuntimeError: sys.path must be a list of directory names. Any ideas? Maybe I am missing a dependency or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using libglade or pygtk as they are dead projects. Use modern PyGObject, Gtk3, and GtkBuilder: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Builder.html